# Laravel 7 migration error: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel

I am running this migration:

```
Schema::create('logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

"Users" table migration (migrated at Laravel 5.8)

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('last_message_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Error that I receive:

```
Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

Comment: What is the order of the migrations? users migration should be run before the logs one.

Comment: Are you sure, the foreign key has exactly the same type and length than yours?

Comment: @Aashishgaba "users" is already created and now I'm trying to create "logs" table

Comment: @GreenPepper yes, I have not changed "id" field in "users" table

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you ran the users migration with a previous version of laravel. Have a look with a db tool (like phpmyadmin, Sequel, etc.) what the actual data type of your users.id field is.

I assume it's not bigInteger so your solution could be to just use

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/XtxSFm1 - This is the type of "users.id" column, it seems correct

Comment: leave out "$table->foreign...", run migration, does it run? Compare fields logs.user_id and users.id in db tool again

Comment: 5.8 uses `unsignedBigInteger` as default